# xpath filtering items with a particular element

Tags: xpath, terminology

I am not sure of the terminology so am having some trouble finding leads.
Basically suppose I have something like

```
<book>
   <genre>sci-fi</genre>
   <genre>happy</genre>
</book>
<book>
   <genre>romance</genre>
</book>
```

And I want to query for a list of books that don't have "sci-fi" as one of the genres.
I tried something simple like

```
//book[//book/genre != "sci-fi"]
```

With the idea that it will return all of the books that do not have a genre element with "sci-fi" value, but it would still return the first one because one of its genre isn't "sci-fi"

Also, how would I phrase this question in a way that people will have an idea what I am talking about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term for the square bracket is a predicate.  You are looking for elements of book which do not have a child element called genre with text of "sci-fi".  This one will match all books with at least one genre that is not sci-fi.

```
//book[genre != "sci-fi"]
```

The following will do what you want:

```
//book[not(genre = 'sci-fi')]
```

And note that you can then add additional paths to the end of that, so if your book had a `title` element you could get all of the titles with:

```
//book[not(genre = 'sci-fi')]/title
```

Comment: At first glance, they seem to mean the same thing logically. Why does that "not" work when != doesn't?

Comment: `[genre != "sci-fi"]` means "match those that have at least one genre which isn't sci-fi".  `[not(genre = 'sci-fi')]` means "do not match those that do have at least one genre equal to sci-fi".